# solving a system of 2 equations with 4 variables

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone show me how to solve this system of equations?
\begin{align}
4X+12Y-7Z-20W&=22 \\
3X+9Y-5Z-28W&=30
\end{align}

Does this mean that there are two free variables here?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: And one of the free variables has to be either $X$ or $Y$.

Comment: Fix two of them (treat them as constants) and solve the two linear equations for the two remaining unknowns. But take care : see what happens if you multiply the first equation by $3$ and the second by $3$.